# How to "restart" the loop so that both Python lists are complete before the program ends?

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to create a program in which the user enters 3 fruits and 3 nonfruits into two different lists.

The user first chooses the first list by typing in "fruits" or "nonfruits". 
The user then enters each qualifying item until the first list is full.

My issue is that once the first selected list is full, the program ends.
I want the user to be prompted to enter in data into the other list until it also is full.

I thought that adding in the "while len(fruits) < 3 and len(notfruits) < 3:" would work, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

How can I do this?

```
fruits = []
notfruits = []
print(fruits)
print(notfruits)
print("Please enter fruits or notfruits:")
y = str(input(": "))
while len(fruits) < 3 and len(notfruits) < 3:
    if y == "fruits":
        while len(fruits) < 3:
            x = str(input(": "))
            x = x.strip()
            if x in notfruits:
                print(x + " is not a fruit!")
            elif x in fruits:
                print(x + " is already in the list!")
            else:
                fruits.append(x)
                print(fruits)
    elif y == "notfruits":
         while len(notfruits) < 3:
            x = str(input(": "))
            x = x.strip()
            if x in fruits:
                print(x + " is a fruit!")
            elif x in notfruits:
                print(x + " is already in the list!")
            else:
                notfruits.append(x)
                print(notfruits)
    else:
        print("Not a valid option!")
```

Comment: To repeatedly enter items for a list, you put the code to accept an entry in a loop.  So to repeatedly accept entries for different lists, put the code to fill a single list within a loop.

Comment: Hi, didn't read all the code but when you say in the code `while len(fruits) < 3 and len(notfruits) < 3:` the condition would skip whenever fruits becomes full: len(fruits) = 3, so the code should rather be `while len(fruits) < 3 or len(notfruits) < 3:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Consider using `or` instead of `and`
2. Move the input part inside the loop, or else `y` will never change

Here's what I mean:

```
fruits = []
notfruits = []
print(fruits)
print(notfruits)

while len(fruits) < 3 or len(notfruits) < 3:   # replaced `and` with `or`
    print("Please enter fruits or notfruits:") #
    y = str(input(": "))                       # moved the input here
    if y == "fruits":
        while len(fruits) < 3:
            x = str(input(": "))
            x = x.strip()
            if x in notfruits:
                print(x + " is not a fruit!")
            elif x in fruits:
                print(x + " is already in the list!")
            else:
                fruits.append(x)
                print(fruits)
    elif y == "notfruits":
         while len(notfruits) < 3:
            x = str(input(": "))
            x = x.strip()
            if x in fruits:
                print(x + " is a fruit!")
            elif x in notfruits:
                print(x + " is already in the list!")
            else:
                notfruits.append(x)
                print(notfruits)
    else:
        print("Not a valid option!")
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for. I am a total noob when it comes to python, still in the process of learning it, and my loop knowledge is lacking.